# Migration between frameworks

Tags: truffle, embark

How much effort would it be to migrate a Dapp written in embark to truffle or vice-versa? Which parts of the code can be preseved (would work in both frameworks)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both frameworks are fairly similar:

- Contract code would be the same because it is just solidity
- Front end code would be the same because it is just js, html, css

However you would need to change

- Configuration files
- Some of the web3 stuff because truffle uses pudding wrapper around Web3.

They also have different default test frameworks.